# How does one solve $-k(1+(dy/dx)^2)=d^2y/dx^2$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that we have the following ODE:

$$-k \left(1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right)=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

How does one solve this differential equation to solve $y(x)$?

All variables and constants are assumed to be real, and constant $k > 0$.

Comment: Fix the title or the equation, please. They don't match.

Comment: Fixed. My apology..

Comment: No problem ! Have you been asked to solve it or is it just curiosity ?

Comment: I was typing when came John ZHANG's answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$, we get a separable equation,
$$-k(1+g^2)=\frac{dg}{dx}\\\frac{1}{1+g^2}dg=-kdx$$
integrate both sides, you get $\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan(-kx+c)$,

hence $y=\int \tan(-kx+c_1)+c_2=\frac{\log(\cos(c_1-kx))}{k}+c_2$